# How To Do Beep in Matlab of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sound, 16.04, matlab

Condition: unsuccessful system beep from motherboard
Settings: sounds work normally
Differential condition: unsuccessful beep from speakers in Matlab

Enable beep sound in kernel and gnome by reversing the [wikipage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_PC_speaker_beep)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences audible-bell true
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

Unsuccessful test code in Terminal

```
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep
echo -ne '\007' 
echo -n ^G
```

Unsuccessful Test code in Matlab

```
beep on 
beep 
sound(1) % so you know when done
fprintf(1,'%c',7) % ASCII beep character

fprintf(1,'\a')

dos(['•&' 'exit&'])
```

Successful Differential Attempts from Speakers not motherboard [Warning loud noise for long time!] in Terminal

```
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163716/16920
#speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 -l 1 # long time
# Same with controlled duration
( speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 )& pid=$! ; sleep 0.1s ; kill -9 $pid
```

Unsuccesful Matlab attempts with Speakers

```
x = [0:0.01:1]; 
soundsc(x) 
soundsc(x, sin(x))
```

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.4 and 4.6
Linux kernel options: wl, pcspkr
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid, ultrabooks

Comment: Obviously Macbook does not have pc speaker.

Comment: This is completely a different question.

Comment: PC Speaker is not installed in any laptops I know. Not only Macbooks.

Comment: like this `cat /dev/urandom | padsp tee /dev/audio > /dev/null` ?

Comment: @kenn Yes,  there is a controlled attempt already in the body, see *Successful Differential Attempts*. Now, it is time to do it in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Linux kernel changes

```
sudo rmmod pcspkr # no speakers in laptop
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences audible-bell false # no motherboard beep in Macbooks
```

Matlab proposals for a snap sound because `soundsc` of a factor is oscillating so only a few is succeeding

```
beep off % disable Matlab beep because no motherboard beep 

soundsc(230) 
soundsc(230) 
soundsc(230)
soundsc(230) 
soundsc(230) 
soundsc(230)
```

Clearer single snap sound would be great!